# Open popup link in same window

Tags: web-mapping, popup, arcgis-platform

I'm using a webmap on my page. The webmap contains layers with popups. These popups contain a link with url GET parameters (ex: www.example.com?id=123)

Is there a way to force the link to open in the same window? How do I capture the GET parameter on this page?

Answer (score 1):

Use: [target="_top"](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) :

**Opens the linked document in the full body of the window**

In your HTML create a syntax like this:

```
<a href="http://[your link.com]" target="_top">link text</a>
```

Comment: There's no where to add a target attribute in the Configure Popup window/tool.

Comment: Oh this is ArcGIS... well... can you post a screen shot of the pop-up window HTML config?

Comment: Yes, this is ArcGIS. I'm simply embedding it in a webpage. Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/2sVwN8Z.png

Comment: ahhhh I see... yeah That's a limitation of the tools I think... using any other web mapping framework you can use the method I described above... sorry It won't help you here!

Comment: I found this https://geonet.esri.com/thread/45086 looks like it is a limitation. :(

Comment: @dam ok good to know!